# Given a post X, select all the posts Y such that no user who rated them both, liked them both

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose a table named 'users', a table named 'posts' and a table named 'ratings', that contains the rating (either a 'like' or 'dislike') of each user towards each post.

```
create table ratings (
user_id int unsigned not null,
post_id int unsigned not null,
rating set('like','dislike') not null,
primary key (user_id, post_id)
);
```

Given a post X, I want to select all the posts Y such that no user who rated them both, liked them both. Furthermore, if possible, I would like to order those posts by the amount of common users who rated them, meaning that the post Y with most common 'raters' with X should appear first.

I'd copy what I've done so far, but I think none of it is worth it. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09973/6). I'm not 100% sure I got what you wanted, but... check with your own data if it fits.

You can also remove the `WHERE` and add `X.post_id AS this_post_id` into the `FROM` to get this for all posts.

Comment: I shouldn't have asked this question so late, I need to sleep now, but as soon as I get up I will try your idea and let you know, it looks great. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

> Given a post X, I want to select all the posts Y such that no user who rated them both, liked them both.

Ok, so given the following set of data you expect 5 and 6 when ID = 1 (I understand you don't want to display ID = 1 either):

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| POST_ID | USER_ID | RATING  |
+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 | like    | // ID = 1, so remove this post
|       1 |       2 | like    |
|       1 |       3 | like    |
|       1 |       4 | dislike |
|       2 |       1 | like    | // Double like, so remove this post
|       2 |       2 | dislike |
|       2 |       3 | like    |
|       2 |       4 | dislike |
|       3 |       1 | like    | // Double like, so remove this post
|       4 |       1 | dislike |
|       4 |       2 | like    | // Double like, so remove this post
|       5 |       1 | dislike |
|       5 |       2 | dislike |
|       5 |       5 | dislike |
|       6 |       1 | dislike |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

This query will give you that:

```
select distinct post_id from ratings r3
where r3.post_id not in (
  select r2.post_id from ratings r1
  join ratings r2
  on r1.post_id <> r2.post_id and r1.user_id = r2.user_id
  where (r1.post_id = 1 or r2.post_id = 1) and r1.rating = 'like' and r2.rating = 'like'
)
```

If you also want them sorted by the common raters both have, then run this query:

```
select post_id from ratings r3
where r3.post_id not in (
  select r2.post_id from ratings r1
  join ratings r2
  on r1.post_id <> r2.post_id and r1.user_id = r2.user_id
  where (r1.post_id = 1 or r2.post_id = 1) and r1.rating = 'like' and r2.rating = 'like'
) and r3.user_id in (
  select user_id from ratings
  where post_id = 1
)
group by post_id
order by count(*) desc
```

Here is an [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/160ad/1)

Comment: Will miss cases where `r2 = like` and `r1 = dislike`, and where both are `dislike`. Also, you don't need to check for `r1.user_id <> r2.user_id` since, being primary key, they would resolve to the same row; and one row can't be both `like` and `dislike` at the same time.

Comment: To be honest I don't get your comment. Each row will be traversed and compared agains all the others for different users so there won't be any miss. I agree with you on the extra condition but actually it would be faster to compare user_ids agains each other than ratings agains each other. Can you provide a set of data in which this query provides a wrong answer?

Comment: I didn't notice you looked up all the rows. OP's request had "given a post X", so you need to collect both `r1` and `r2` in your case, since they're not symmetric. Anyway, there is the bad case in the previous comment: a user rating both `r1` and `r2` as `dislike` should be in the answer, but you disallow it.

Comment: Because the previous answer worked, I didn't test yours, but it seems ok, and I took your strategy of ordering by count() instead of selecting the count with an alias like the other answer did, so a well deserved +1, thanks!